# Undefined index when do AJAX request in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

For some reason when I do my AJAX request in my `main.js` file, I get an error:

```
Undefined index: id in sqlinfo.php on line 13
```

And I'm not sure why because I feel that I am filling out the `request` object correctly. What's also strange is that this works:

```
$requestType = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'requestType', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

So why doesn't `$_POST['id']` work?

If anyone could tell me what error I'm making that would be great!

**Note:** I know `albumId` has a value because I already used `console.log()` to verify that it has a value.

### Code

*main.js*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".grid").on("click", ".edit", function (){
      var albumId = $(this).siblings(".grid-info").attr("id");
      var imageId = $(this).siblings("img").attr("id");
      var request = (albumId == '') ? {requestType: 'Album', id: albumId} : {requestType: 'Image', id: imageId};
      var getSQLInfo = $.ajax({
        url: '../P3_M2/ajax/sqlinfo.php',
        method: 'post',
        data: request,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
        });

});
```

*sqlinfo.php*

```
<?php
require_once('../configsql.php');

$queryFor = array(
  'Album' => 'SELECT * FROM Album WHERE id = ?',
  'Image' => 'SELECT * FROM Image WHERE id = ?');

$requestType = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'requestType', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  if (empty($requestType)) {
    echo 'Missing requestType.';
    die();
  }
$id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id']); //getting undefined index id
?>
```

Comment: what about imageId does it has a value?

Comment: No but that's irrelevant since the ternary operator ensures that `request` will become `{requestType: 'Album', id: albumId}`

Comment: then print request and see

Comment: oh! i realized i did the wrong operation, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @v Sugumar I realized I had the wrong boolean (`==`) when I assigned `request`. Changing  it to `!=` fixed it:

```
var request = (albumId != '') ? {requestType: 'Album', id: albumId} : {requestType: 'Image', id: imageId};
```